# Is This Polyhedron Formula Correct?

Tags: geometry

I am referring to the this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume), which states that the way to find the volume of a Polyhedron can be done via Divergence Theorem:

$$\int \nabla \cdot \vec{F} dV=\oint \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS$$

By choosing

$$ \vec{F}=\frac{\vec{x}}{3}$$

One can then obtain the volume formula for a polyhedron with $k$ faces:

$$V = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k \vec{x_{i}} \cdot \hat{n_i} A_i}{3}$$

where $\vec{x_{i}}$,$\hat{n_i}$ and $A_i$ are a point, normal vector and the area of the face $i$. (<del>The wiki page doesn't say $x_i$ is the centroid; it just says that it can be any point on the face, but I believe that it must be centroid, or else the volume obtained not correct</del>, The $x_i$ can be any point; see comments)

My question is, is my formula and interpretation correct? And does it hold for all kinds of polyhedron, be it convex or concave?

Comment: Green's theorem applies to 2D regions not 3D. Perhaps you meant [Divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)?

Comment: @Moron, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Two points on face $i$ differ by a vector which is orthogonal to $n_i$. It follows that $x_i$ can be any point on face $i$.

Comment: @Christian, now I see it, thanks! Question will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The quoted formula holds for any polyhedral surface $S$, or even for a collection of polyhedral surfaces $S_i$, that (together) bound(s) a "volume" $V\subset {\mathbb R}^3$. It is true that a polyhedron has edges and vertices. Therefore, depending on the proof that was originally given for the divergence theorem, one might need an approximation argument to apply the theorem to polyhedra.

Comment: I see. But what about a "cut-through" polyhedron, like the one showing [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15739/does-green-theorem-polyhedron-volume-calculation-applicable-for-a-cut-through-pol)?